# Diophantine Equations Problem

Tags: diophantine-equations, integers

Find all **positive integers** $x, y, z$ such that $x^2y+y^2z+z^2x = 3xyz$.

> I first tried to solve it by spilting $xyz$ to every expression and factor it. But it fails.

I notice that it is true for $\left(x,y,z\right) = \left(0,0,0\right)$. But how can I prove all of then and find the values ?

Comment: This is equivalent to $\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{z}+\frac{z}{x}=3$.

Comment: But can you please the proses to get in this form

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Here's [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Follow these guidelines to get help in this forum. It's particularly important that you share your own work and thoughts on the problem to show that you have made a serious effort by yourself before asking for help, and you're not just trying to get others to solve it for you.

Comment: You should notice that this equation is symmetric in $x$, $y$, and $z$. You can split this into multiple cases: The case where $x=0$ - see where this leads you and then use symmetry to deduce the cases when $y=0$ and when $z=0$. The next set of cases would be for when non of $x, y, z$ are zero. There you can divide the equation on both sides by $xyz$ to get the equation that @DietrichBurde showed above. See what you can then deduce about this equation.

Comment: Actually, after re-reading the question, I see that we should only consider **positive integers** which means we can ignore the case of zeros.

Comment: See also [Indian Postal Training Set 3, Problem 5, 2010](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h381659p2113392).

Answer (score 5):

By [AM-GM](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means) inequality, you have:

$$x^2y+y^2z+z^2x=3xyz≥3xyz$$

Equality holds iff, when $x^2y=y^2z=z^2x\thinspace.$

Thus we have:

$$\begin{align}&\begin{cases}x^2=yz\\y^2=xz\\z^2=xy\end{cases}\\
\implies &\left(\frac xy\right)^2=\frac yx\\
\implies &\left(\frac xy\right)^3=1\\
\implies &x=y\end{align}$$

This yields, $x=y=z$ are only possible solution. Note that, $(x,y,z)=(x,x,x)\in\mathbb R^3_{≥0}$ are also solution set.

Comment: Yes - just re-read which is why I immediately deleted my comment - sorry

Answer (score 2):

If you assume one of the variables is $0$ (say $x=0$), then we must have $y^{2}z = 0$, so either $y=0$, $z=0$ or both, hence the triples $\left(0,0,k\right)$, $\left(0,k,0\right)$ and $\left(k,0,0\right)$ are solutions for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, now, if $xyz \neq 0$ we can divide both sides of the equation by $xyz$ and we get

$$
\frac{x}{z} +\frac{y}{x}+\frac{z}{y} = 3.
$$

By $AM \geq GM$ we have that $\frac{x}{z} +\frac{y}{x}+\frac{z}{y}\geq 3$ with equality iff

$$
\frac{x}{z} =\frac{y}{x}=\frac{z}{y}
$$

which can only happens if $x=y=z$, so the only other solutions are $\left(k,k,k\right)$ with $k\in \mathbb{Z}$.